# image returns value “null” using JS

Tags: javascript

In my web page I have an image, which I want to print it using javascript but the id of the image in JS is always null. Please advise me what to do..

```
<div class="reportFieldsDiv" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
                <table style="width: 400px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px; border: 1px solid black">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Images/Layout/TestBadge.jpg" alt="ID Badge" id="mainImage"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div style="border: 0px solid black;padding:5px 0px 0px 280px">
                  <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" Width="140px" />

                </div>
            </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function () {
            var image = document.getElementById('mainImage');
            printImage(image);
        };


        function printImage(image) {
            var printWindow = window.open('', 'Print Window', 'height=400,width=600');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Window</title>');

            printWindow.document.write('<img id="mainImage" src=\'..\Images\Layout\TestBadge.jpg');
            printWindow.document.write(image.src);
            printWindow.document.write('\' /></body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
        }


    </script>
```

Comment: I believe ASP.NET Webforms will assign a different ID if you're using `runat=server`. Check the actual id of the image using your brower's inspector.

Comment: That was a quick fix thank you, but now I want to open my image in popup window and fire the print event but for some reason the image won't coming up can you help me with that?

Comment: `Runat = Server` won't work for "classic ASP", and it won't work at all besides with Microsoft.  Don't do it if you don't absolutely need it - and consider trying a different design otherwise.  If you get rid of the "runat=Server", I suspect it "might just work".  IMHO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add the id to the `printWindow` document as seen below:

```
printWindow.document.write('<img id="mainImage" src="..\Images\Layout\TestBadge.jpg"');
```

Comment: For some reason the I don't see the image when the popup window is coming up. how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know why your image isn't popping up. I don't have that image so when I use your html it doesn't come up for me anyways. One thing that I think is wrong is your quotes are wrong in your string. I will edit my answer to make the quotes correct.